# Testing treeviews in a web application with the use of CodedUI (Visual Studios 2013 C#)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, treeview, coded-ui-tests

As stated in the title I'm writing/recording a C# based CodedUI test for a web application. The controls that I'm having a problem recording/mapping is the TreeView controls. The problem with the test is selecting a specific element.

As an example I have a treeview that has the following set up:

- A

  - A1
  - A2
- B

  - B1
  - B2
- C

  - C1
  - C2
- D

  - D1
  - D2
- E

  - E1
  - E2

Lets say that I want to select the element D1. I start recording I open up the category D by pressing the arrow beside the "D" (Categoryname), and then proceed to select D1. Once I'm replaying the instance, without altering any of the code, the category that is opened is A and the element selected is "D" (The category group). So I get that the arrow doesn't specify which category it expands that's why it opens the category "A". I have no idea why it selects the category "D".

I've tried to alter the "SearchProperties" in the code but without any luck. I've tried to use the TagInstance but that lead the test to not find any control at all. I've tried to set other SearchProperties (and FilterProperties) but without any luck.

Is there anyone who has encountered, and solved, this problem? If so would you mind helping me out. Thank you!

PS.
I've read some and someone stated that the problem would be solved by setting "PlaybackSettings.MatchExactHierarchy" to true but it did not work.

Edit;

I sadly don't have access to the code that generates the controls but I can send an image of the control and the Search properties that are generated.

[Treeview control looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4vCZ2.png)

and here's the search properties defined for the category "ServiceDesk":

```
this.mUIItemPane.SearchProperties[HtmlDiv.PropertyNames.Class] = "k-mid";
this.mUIItemPane.SearchProperties[HtmlSpan.PropertyNames.Class] = "k-icon k-plus";
this.mUIItemPane.SearchProperties[HtmlSpan.PropertyNames.TagName] = "SPAN";
this.mUIItemPane.SearchProperties[HtmlSpan.PropertyNames.ControlDefinition] = "class=\"k-icon k-plus\" role=\"presentation\"";
```

(Note that this is the SearchProperties for the arrow beside the category name "ServiceDesk" and not the text itself)

and for the user "Farhad":

```
this.mUIFarhadPane.SearchProperties[HtmlDiv.PropertyNames.Id] = null;
this.mUIFarhadPane.SearchProperties[HtmlDiv.PropertyNames.Name] = null;
this.mUIFarhadPane.FilterProperties[HtmlDiv.PropertyNames.InnerText] = "Farhad";
this.mUIFarhadPane.FilterProperties[HtmlDiv.PropertyNames.Title] = null;
this.mUIFarhadPane.FilterProperties[HtmlDiv.PropertyNames.Class] = "k-in";
this.mUIFarhadPane.FilterProperties[HtmlDiv.PropertyNames.ControlDefinition] = "class=\"k-in\"";
this.mUIFarhadPane.FilterProperties[HtmlDiv.PropertyNames.TagInstance] = "337";
```

Another thing that might be of use is the following control information:

[The arrow and user element in the treeview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PATN2.png)

Comment: Could you post the code that defines the controls in question?  I'd still wager that the search properties are defined in a way that creates these problems.

Comment: @RyanCox Thank you for your reply. I've edited the original post to be a bit more specific.

Comment: @Arha - Search properties for "ServiceDesk" are not proper. This would find the first arrow on page and not the ServiceDesk parent. 
Can you post the HTML snippet of the image of TreeView control you just posted.

Comment: @SarkarG - Of course, I'll post two screenshots of the source, if it isn't enough just tell me and I'll add the source itself. http://imgur.com/a/KgMWK

Comment: I saw your source screenshot. It seems like a "Kendo" Treeview control. I think record and playback won't be much helpful here and you may need to create some custom method like what i posted below. It is simple. You can try it yourself. First find treeview. then find then div containing parent node name("ServiceDesk") by looking for InnerText. Click on the first child of this div which will probably be the expand/collapse icon. Then find the next sibling of this div which would be an UL, which will contain all the children. Look for the child node by matching the innertext from the LI in UL.

Comment: @SarkarG - Thank you for your help. I'll try it out, and update you with the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you are automating on usual asp TreeView control. The structure generated on web is something like this.

```
<table>......
<tr> 
    <td> <a>+(Expand Icon)</a> </td>
    <td> <a>PARENT NODE NAME</a> </td>
</tr>....  
<table>
<div>
 <table>....<a>CHILD NODE 1</a>....</table>
 <table>....<a>CHILD NODE 2</a>....</table>
</div>
```

Using this structure we can easily create our own method to click thing on treeview.

```
    public void ClickTreeviewChildItem(string parent, string child)
    {
        // Suppose TreeView control Id is MyTreeView. 
        var treeView = new HtmlDiv(new TreeViewPageMap().UIHttplocalhost38842DeWindow); // Use your uimap window here
        treeView.SearchProperties.Add(HtmlDiv.PropertyNames.Id, "MyTreeView");
        treeView.Find();

        // click on parent
        var parentNode = new HtmlHyperlink(treeView);
        parentNode.SearchProperties.Add(HtmlHyperlink.PropertyNames.InnerText, parent);
        Mouse.Click(parentNode);

        // Get id of plus sign in front of node parent node - should be like "MyTreeViewn9"
        // <tr>
        //  <td><a> - </a> </td>
        //  <td><a> D </a> </td> 
        var expandCollapseIconLink = parentNode.GetParent().GetParent().GetChildren()[0].GetChildren()[0] as HtmlHyperlink;
        var linkId = expandCollapseIconLink.Id;

        // Get child div of clicked parent
        // Child div id will be nothing but suffix "Nodes" attached with the id of expand collapse which we got in previous step
        var childDiv = new HtmlDiv(treeView);
        childDiv.SearchProperties.Add(HtmlDiv.PropertyNames.Id, linkId + "Nodes");
        childDiv.Find();

        // find all links as child links in this div
        var allLink = new HtmlHyperlink(childDiv);
        var allLinks = allLink.FindMatchingControls();
        var linkToClick = allLinks.Cast<HtmlHyperlink>().FirstOrDefault(a => a.InnerText.Trim().Equals(child)); // Using System.Linq;
        Mouse.Click(linkToClick);
    }
```

Even if the structure of your treeview is different, you can try the same approach of finding and clicking nodes. Tested this method on this structure.

[image]

Comment: I will try to apply this solution but the structure of the treeview control added is actually several list items with several unorded lists underneath it.

If I understood this solution correctly this should be used as a method inside a testcase and stored in the UIMap class, is that correct? This way I will call the method with the parameters "ServiceDesk" and the parameter "Farhad" and it should select this item.

Thank you very much for the time you spent writing an answer! I really appreciate it.